# How to solve "MySQL service can not start" error in laragon 5.0.0 when adding a new version of MySQL

Tags: mysql, laragon

Hello guys i need your help to add a new version of MySQL in Laragon (version 5.0.0). Currently I'm using MySQL 5.7.33 and I would like to upgrade to 8.0.28 but unfortunately after trying to add it I got the following error (you can see the details below):

> Failed:mysql-8.0.28-winx64
>
> MySQL service can't start

[laragon mysql error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLsK9.png)

Here's how I did it:

1. I downloaded mysql-8.0.28-winx64.rar file and extracted it to C:\laragon\bin\mysql
2. And in laragon main window i add it in the following way :
   Menu>MYSQL>mysql-5.7.33-winx64>mysql-8.0.28-winx64

After pressing "start all" I get this error: "Service MySQL can not start".

I tried to tweak a bit in the my.ini file but still no solution.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

would like to share My solution for this I used 64bit version and its in my PC "D" drive with no mysql root password

1.Install c++ redistribution package from Microsoft site "VC_redist.x64.exe"

2-Download mysql8.0.x-winx64.zip archive

3-Extract to "D:\laragon\bin\mysql" directory change drive letter accordingly

4-Stop laragon and and select mysql8.0-winx64 version from Laragon Menu ->version->mysql-8.0.x-win64

5-Now start the Service wait for few seconds to allow initialization

6-Stop mysql server go to directory "D:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.x-winx64\bin" run "mysqld stop" this will stop sql

7-Go to "D:\laragon\data" rename existing "mysql-8" folder to mysql.bk and rename "mysql" folder to mysql-8

8-Stop Laragon and restart it again

open cmd.exe as Administrator

9-go to directory "D:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.x-winx64" run "mysql_upgrade.exe -u root -p" I didnt have password so i left it blank after -p

10-Click Enter without password when prompted Wait for Few minutes to allow mysql do the upgrade

11-now go to mysql terminal from Laragon enter comand "mysql -u root -p" Click Enter without password

12.Now enter the following comand "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';" replace NewPassword with your own one

13.Now Restart Laragon again

If you have Phpmyadmin installed it should work now if you dont have install it from add feature

Chears

Comment: His folder structure is wrong. please see my answer below

Comment: This worked for my upgrade to 8.0.28. Just have to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

I found it worked just by following these 4 steps, changing the volume and path to your installed directory

1. Stop All
2. Rename folder C:\laragon\data\mysql-8 to C:\laragon\data\mysql-8.bak
3. Rename C:\laragon\data\mysql to C:\laragon\data\mysql-8
4. Start All

The directory on your nominated drive laragon\data\mysql is the data directory for MySQL 5.7. When you change to mysql-8, Laragon will upgrade that data directory to MySQL 8 format.

Answer (score 0):

check your folder structure. Now your folder structure is like this
**laragon/bin/mysql/mysql-8.0.13-winx64/mysql-8.0.13-winx64**

change to  **laragon/bin/mysql/mysql-8.0.13-winx64**

Answer (score 0):

I enountered the same error a while ago, but these steps were able to solve it instantly, you don't have to over think it. Follow along and it will fix your error

1. Make sure there isn't any other server installed on your PC like XAMPP if you install multiple server in same PC it can cause port issues.
2. Make sure you installed laragon in your C drive.
3. Reinstall: uninstall laragon app then go to the path where you installed the laragon in there you will find a laragon folder delete that folder and reinstall the app again.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem, even though i have this mysql-8.0.13-winx64 install
what did was the change the port number of any other sql service that was running in my machine like in xampp i change the port number from 3306 to 3307 then run my laragon it work

Answer (score -1):

if you try to change port number and is not working Just uninstall XAMPP, restart your system and your Laragon should be working fine again